# GNU GRUB exit mac os

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, grub-efi, refind

I have a Macbook Air. I installed Ubuntu with dual boot. But I wanted to delete it. I deleted rEFInd. Then I restarted and I got to GNU GRUB. When I write command exit it froze. When I try to access to recovery mode I cannot see anything --  there is no Mac OS X disk. How can I get back to Mac OS?

Answer (score 1):

Try holding down the Option (or Alt) key as you power on the computer and it sounds its chime. This should bring up the computer's built-in boot manager.

If that fails, and if the computer boots to Ubuntu, you could do one or more of three things:

- **Use `efibootmgr`** -- The `efibootmgr` tool controls the computer's boot order. Typing `sudo efibootmgr` shows the entries. There should be an entry for `ubuntu`, which you can delete with `sudo efibootmgr -b #### -B`, where `####` is the boot number; or you can use `-o` to set a new boot order, as in `sudo efibootmgr -o 80,81,82` to set `Boot0080` first, `Boot0081` second, and so on. (OS X generally uses `0080` and above for itself.)
- **Delete GRUB** -- Ubuntu installs GRUB in the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` directory (`EFI/ubuntu` on the [EFI System Partition [ESP]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)). Deleting this directory, or at least the `grubx64.efi` and `shimx64.efi` files it contains, will prevent it from running. The computer should then try the next available boot entry, which should be OS X; or enter an automatic recovery tool.
- **Reset the NVRAM** -- See [this official Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) for information on how to reset the computer's NVRAM. I'm not 100% sure of this, but I believe that doing so will reset the boot order options, thus solving your problem. (Note that this should work even without access to Ubuntu.)

Comment: How can I do this from macOS? There is no `efibootmgr` installed and no `/boot`  on Catalina.

Comment: @lpacheco, you could use an Ubuntu installation CD in its "try before installing" mode to access `efibootmgr`. In macOS, you can mount the ESP manually at `/Volumes/ESP` by typing `mkdir /Volumes/ESP` followed by sudo `mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/ESP', with the caveat that this *assumes* the ESP is `/dev/disk0s1`, as it is on most Macs. To determine that with absolute certainty, you'd need to study the output of `diskutil list`.